# Bootstrap and Telerik Controls

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, telerik

I have an Asp.net site which is styled using Bootstrap CSS and I need to add a bunch of Telerik control to it.

The issue I am facing is that the bootstrap.css is overwriting the css from the Telerik controls making them look odd.

Can I create a div/Panel which I can specify to not apply any bootstrap css to? If yes then how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Bootstrap specific CSS for the Telerik controls as stated in the documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap)

> 1. Use the kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css instead of kendo.common.css. This ensures that the dimensions of Kendo UI will match the ones in Bootstrap.
> 2. Use the kendo.bootstrap.min.css theme, which applies the Bootstrap colors to the Kendo UI widgets.